# how to fix an apple silicon arm64 program thats getting an error saying that two of the variables are not 4 aligned

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, apple-m1, arm64

The error that I am getting is complaining about one of the string variables and the input variable that is set to six for testing. It says that they are not 4 aligned. This is on my mac mini with an m1 chip

The following code is meant to calculate the next value in the collatz conjecture formula (3n+1 if odd, n/2 if even). It isn't complete but I was testing to make sure the even and odd was working and I got the error.

```
.global _main

.align 4



_main:

        b _modulo

        b _collatz

        b _terminate



_collatz:

    cbz X3, _printEven

        cbnz X3, _printOdd



_modulo:

    adr X0, input

    mov X1, #2

        udiv X2, X0, X1

        msub X3, X2, X1, X0



_printOdd:

        mov X0, #1

        adr X1, odd

        mov X2, #4

        mov X16, #4

        svc 0

        b _ifOdd



_ifOdd:

        adr X0, input

        mov X2, #3

        mov X1, #1

        madd X3, X2, X0, X1



_printEven:

        mov X0, #1

        adr X1, even

        mov X2, #5

        mov X16, #4

        svc 0

        b _ifEven



_ifEven:

        adr X0, input

        mov X1, #2

        udiv X2, X0, X1



_terminate:

    mov X0, #0

        mov X16, #1

        svc 0 



even: .ascii "even\n"

odd: .ascii "odd\n"

input: #6
```

Edit: I have realized instead of the stuff currently in the modulo I could just check the last bit of input for the even or odd

Comment: After the line `cbnz X3, _printOdd`, what line do you think executes next?

Comment: I think it would go to _printOdd and execute  ```mov X0, #1```

Comment: @fuz: If `cbnz X3, _printOdd` is reached at all, it's with non-zero X3 so the jump is taken.  It's inefficient and confusing to have another conditional branch on the opposite condition, but execution can't fall through past it.  (Confusing because the choice of a conditional branch instead of unconditional `b` implies that there's something that needs checking, that some conditional behaviour is needed.)

Comment: Of course if we're talking about efficiency, `udiv` by #2 instead of a right shift by 1 is a much bigger problem. (Like in an x86 version: [Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40354978))

Comment: @PeterCordes yes I just realized this and will fix it when I have access to my mac. Thanks for noticing

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the udiv. Why does this work as I am not super confident with right shift

Comment: [Can anyone explain why '>>2' shift means 'divided by 4' in C codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13577174) - computers use binary (base 2), so dividing by 2 in a computer is as easy as dividing by 10 in a decimal number, just drop the low digit.